# загрузка csv в БД SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql, csv

Необходимо загрузить большой csv файл в БД (1,5 Гб). Пробовал делать построчную запись с помощью INSERT - это очень долго. 100 000 строк загружается примерно 2 минуты. В файле 120 000 000 строк. Прочитал, что можно использовать SQLBulkCopy и это будет в разы быстрее. Но вопрос в том, можно ли сделать загрузку CSV с разбивкой по столбцам? Например у меня в CSV Series и Number столбцы с разделителем ",". Таблица тоже с двумя аналогичными столбцами. Есть какие-нибудь еще более быстрые способы загрузки или как сделать мапинг полей

```
string line = "";
       string con_str = "server;Database=base;Trusted_Connection=True;";
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con_str))
       {
            connection.Open();
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(@"D:\bzip2\WriteLines.csv"), 10 * 1024 * 1024)))
            {
                //string table = "ElmaBadPassport";

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {   
                    if (line.Length == 11)
                    {   string[] values = line.Split(',');
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO ElmaBadPassport(Series,Number) VALUES (@series, @number)",connection);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@series",values[0].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", values[1].ToString());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
       }
```

Comment: Если сделать это надо один раз можно воспользоваться мастером импорта /экспорта в SSMS.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov он тормознутый и вставляет по 1 записи. ESF Migration Tool kit рулит и делает это шустро.

Comment: @iluxa1810 если речь о скорости, то тогда уже через SSIS в несколько потоков грузить, там все также понятно настраивается. Но... автору насколько понимаю надо делать это с помощью C#

Comment: @NickProskuryakov к сожалениию, надо на C# и неоднократно. Написали софтину, которая скачивает исходник, распаковывает, потом создает новый CSV с правильными данными. А далее надо грузить в БД.

Answer (score 0):

Для однократного решения задачи я рекомендую использовать `ESF Migration ToolKit`, который отлично справляется со своей работой в то время, как стандартное средство импорта /экспорта в SSMS делает вставку по 1 записи. Правда минус в том, что он платный...

Если все таки хочется- это самому реализовать, то есть класс `SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping`, где можно задать маппинг одного поля на другое. Однако, хоть СУБД и пофигу на регистр колонок, однако, `BulkCopy` не пофиг и он не найдет соответствие схожих имен, но с разным регистром.

А еще, на сколько я знаю, можно прямо из MS SQL через скрипт сделать BULK INSERT:

```
BULK INSERT SchoolsTemp
    FROM 'C:\CSVData\Schools.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\SchoolsErrorRows.csv',
    TABLOCK
    )
```

Правда, не пробовал.

P.S Ну и не забудь в целевой таблице грохнуть всех индексы и ключи, так это тормозит вставку.

Comment: т.е. SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping съест название колонки, и запишет в нужную при условии что регистры одинаковые?

Comment: @AndreySherman, должен. Ну и на вход должен подаваться DataTable, либо DataReader.